# force https with apache before .htpasswd

Tags: ssl, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have this in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myweb.com/phpmyadmin$1 [R,L]

AuthUserFile /var/www/myweb/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Sovereign Databases"
AuthType Basic

<Limit GET>
require valid-user
</Limit>
```

But everytime I go to http://www.myweb.com/phpmyadmin, the .htpasswd prompts me for a credentials BEFORE i'm redirected to https://www.myweb.com/phpmyadmin.  After I type in my username and password, I get redirected to https://www.myweb.com/phpmyadmin.  The problem is that I don't want anyone to submit their username and password unencrypted via http.

How do I force people to login via the https version even if they typed in the http version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the `Auth` statements to a `<VirtualHost *:443>` block.

(Someone else might have a more elegant and better answer).

Comment: That's actually the most correct and elegant way to do it.

Comment: Do I have to have access to Apache config or can I use it in the .htaccess file ?

Comment: .htaccess applies to all VirtualHosts which access a directory, so no, it wouldn't work that way.